# Install Nvidia drivers on Linux Mint 17.3

Tags: linux-mint, drivers

I need to add additional drivers. In software sources I see:

- Official repositories
- PPAs
- Additional repositories
- Authentication keys
- Maintenance

OS: Linux Mint 17.3

The question is:

How do I install proprietary Nvidia driver?

Comment: For someone to help you, they are likely going to need a lot more information.  Can you spell out in more detail what operating system you are using and precisely what you are trying to do?

Comment: Edited info(Ask if u need more)

Comment: You should have all the necessary informations
[-->here<--](https://johners.tech/2017/01/11/installing-the-latest-nvidia-graphics-drivers-on-linux-mint-18/)

Comment: Check whether this helps http://www.codingdevil.com/2015/04/configure-bumblebee-for-nvidia-optimus.html

Answer (score 2):

**The official way:**

1. Click Menu -> Driver Manager -> enter your password.
2. Select e.g. `nvidia-340` or whatever version currently official is.
3. Click Apply changes, and wait for it to finish.
4. Click Reboot to restart the machine.

**The unofficial way:** I can't recommend it, since I had multiple issues with these drivers myself, but it is entirely up to you and your needs:

1. Add a PPA to your system, from terminal, you will be asked for password:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
   ```
2. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> for it to finish.
3. In the terminal type and confirm:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
4. Proceed from step 1 from The official way, select the version that suites you best.